# Row to Column with Custom Value SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table:

```
oSerial     oDateTime               oMessage1  
--------------------------------------------------
123456      2022-01-01 08:00:00     F1F           
123456      2022-01-01 08:10:00     F2F   
123456      2022-01-01 08:45:00     F5F
123456      2022-01-01 09:05:00     F1N
```

I want to have the following result:

```
oSerial     oDateTime              F1       F2     F3     F4     F5
--------------------------------------------------------------------
123456      2022-01-01 08:00:00    RED      
123456      2022-01-01 08:10:00             RED
123456      2022-01-01 08:45:00                                  RED
123456      2022-01-01 09:05:00    GREEN
```

So, if the last character under `oMessage1` is F, then the value should be `RED`. If the last character under `oMessage1` is N, then the value should `GREEN`. The value will be placed under F1 - F5 column based on 2 characters in the beginning under oMessage1.

Any advice? Really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: First parse `oMessage1`  into two columns then pivot the result.

Comment: Hint : `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, `CASE` expression

Comment: If the list of Fxxxx is not fixed use a dynamic sql. What is your problem exactly, where are you stuck at?

Comment: @Serg, I want to have a dynamic column. Because the 2 characters in the beginning will be more and more. F1 - F100... Don't know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
    SELECT 123456 AS oSerial, '2022-01-01 08:00:00' AS oDateTime, 'F1F' AS oMessage1 UNION ALL           
    SELECT 123456 AS oSerial, '2022-01-01 08:10:00' AS oDateTime, 'F2F' AS oMessage1 UNION ALL   
    SELECT 123456 AS oSerial, '2022-01-01 08:45:00' AS oDateTime, 'F5F' AS oMessage1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 123456 AS oSerial, '2022-01-01 09:05:00' AS oDateTime, 'F1N' AS oMessage1 
)
SELECT oSerial, oDateTime, 
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F1%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F1%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
    END AS f1,
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F2%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F2%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
    END AS f2,
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F3%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F3%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
    END AS f3,
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F4%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F4%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
    END AS f4,
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F5%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F5%' AND oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
    END AS f5
FROM tmp
ORDER BY oSerial, oDateTime;
```

If you have more than 2 colors then you should change to this to avoid duplicate code:

```
CASE WHEN oMessage1 LIKE 'F1%' THEN
    CASE 
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE '%F' THEN 'RED'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE '%N' THEN 'GREEN'
        WHEN oMessage1 LIKE '%O' THEN 'OTHERS COLOR 1'
        --WHEN oMessage1 LIKE '%X' THEN 'OTHERS COLOR X'
    END
END AS f1,
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pham, but how if I have a lot of records?

Comment: @Haminteu then you just change `tmp` to your table name. Or do you mean that you have **F1** to **Fn** and **n** is a big integer, or **n** is not known (maybe change dynamically in future)?

Comment: Just a sign for the value (color). F = RED, N = Green. Yes, I just thinking that maybe it's possible to make it dynamic.

Comment: @Haminteu For more than 2 colors, you could refer to my edited answer. For dynamic color, or dynamic **Fn**, you should search and use pivot with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT oSerial, oDateTime,
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,1,2) = 'F1' THEN 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='F' THEN 'RED' WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='N' THEN 'GREEN' END 
     ELSE null END as F1,
     
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,1,2) = 'F2' THEN 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='F' THEN 'RED' WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='N' THEN 'GREEN' END 
     ELSE null END as F2,
     
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,1,2) = 'F3' THEN 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='F' THEN 'RED' WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='N' THEN 'GREEN' END 
     ELSE null END as F3,
     
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,1,2) = 'F4' THEN 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='F' THEN 'RED' WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='N' THEN 'GREEN' END 
     ELSE null END as F4,
     
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,1,2) = 'F5' THEN 
     CASE WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='F' THEN 'RED' WHEN SUBSTR(oMessage1,3,3)='N' THEN 'GREEN' END 
     ELSE null END as F5
          
          FROM TableName
```